# Using Parents() on an element which gets reinserted on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a dropdown functionality using Jquery with one event listener that allows me to close the dropdown when clicked anywhere outside the dropdown container and another event listener which handles the submenu items.

By design the dropdown should stay open even if the submenu items are clicked and should only close if the toggle button is clicked or the user clicks outside the dropdown container.

**The problem**

Lets say that general.js has the click event listener as follows

```
$('document').on('click.namespace',function(e){ // do stuff });
```

Now anotherscript.js has an event listener which handles the actual sub menu clicks

```
$('#clickbutton').on('click', function(e){ 
         // Remove all html  from inside the .dropdown container 
         // Recreate the html using another js function 
         $('.container').html(recreatedhtml);
});
```

The problem occurs when I try to identify who the parent of the submenu button click target is, because I want to know if the click was inside the container or outside.

Since a click on #clickbutton removes html from the container and reinserts it I believe this causes problems for the parents() function therefore the parents('.dropdown') function returns false even though the sub menu item is a descendent of the dropdown class.

Answer (score 0):

Check the target of the event

```
$(document).on('click.namespace',function(e){ 
   if(!$(e.target).closest(dropdownContainerSelector).length){
      // click is not in dropdown container
   }

 });
```

Note that document is not a string, it is a global object within window

Comment: Hi , tried this and it doesn't work whilst I have a event listener attached to the #clickbutton sub menu link however when I remove that event listener it works . How can I make both work together ?